# Access to private members of a class in grails 3.0

Tags: grails

In grails 2.4.3 it is possible to access a private field in a class outside from the class. See http://refaktor.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/private-fields-and-methods-are-not.html or https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1875.

Is this issue fixed in Grails 3.x? Because we plan to upgrade to the new version and some code access privates already. So I want to know if I have to check every access for a private variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with Grails and is specific to the Groovy programming language.

Comment: So when I upgrade to grails 3.0, does this problem still exists?

Comment: @Peter Yes. As I said what you are asking has absolutely nothing to do with Grails.

Comment: Okay, so Grails 2.4.3 und Grails 3 use the same groovy version? Is this behaviour fixed in in any groovy version?

Comment: @Peter From looking at the `build.gradle` file from `grails-core`, it appears all Grails versions used Groovy 2.4.X and this behavior of the language has been around since Groovy 1.1. The issue was first reported on 03/May/07 17:04 as shown in the issues tracker you linked. It was also updated on 27/Jul/15 12:08, it's unclear whether or not this will be addressed/fixed.